# pipe here document command to log file

Tags: bash, heredoc

Quite often I'll use the following construct to pipe output to a log file, keeping the output also on the display

```
./command 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

I'm trying to do something similar, but with using a here document:

```
./command << HEREDOC
params
HEREDOC 2>&1 | tee output.log
```

This doesn't work - is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sure.

```
./command <<HEREDOC 2>&1 | tee output.log
params
HEREDOC
```

The here-document doesn't begin until the next line.  The rest of the command is parsed as normal.

Comment: works even with [line continuation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html#Escape-Character) (``\``). For example, write ``./command <<HEREDOC \`` in the first line and ``2>&1 | tee output.log`` in the second line.

Comment: Great.It works.where you find the documents of this solution?

Comment: Here-documents are described in [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents). It doesn't explicitly say that the here-doc starts on the next line, but that's implied by the way the shell reads and parses commands in conjunction with the statement that a here-document "instructs the shell to read input from the current source". The shell doesn't start to do anything based on a command until it has read the whole command.

Answer (score 2):

An example with `expr`:

```
xargs expr << HEREDOC | tee output.log
10 + 11
HEREDOC
```